# Is there a portability risk with Heroku?

Tags: facebook, heroku

I am trying to develop a simple Facebook web application, and I am fairly new to both FB app development and to web application development in general. I had been looking for a way to quickly start and learn, and I came across Heroku.
It seems like a good platform for me to learn the ropes of Facebook application development, but my fear is that if I get to a point where I want my app to continue growing, or if I want to start doing more advanced things with it, then I would have to move to something like Amazon's Web services to make it economical right? In that case, would such a move be terribly difficult to make? In other words, if I start to learn Facebook App development on Heroku, will I become 'tied' to the platform and unable to build/run a Facebook app on any other platform? Or do you think Heroku is a good way for a beginner like me to start learning with the option of moving my app elsewhere once I get proficient enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am fairly new to both FB app development and to web application development in general.

Then you should not need to worry about being stuck in a platform. The platform you end up with will be a result of various blocks that you encounter as well as pros and cons from experience working on your specific application.

The Facebook API and all official SDKs are independent of the platform. Code is also never written just once, you will encounter refactoring. So, transferring your application is a part of the process, some transfer routes will be more difficult than others but you will learn along the way.

Heroku is fine, you will be able to learn, git, unix commands and web development all in one.

So no, there is no portability risk for someone learning Facebook development.